# SQL LIKE '[AMD]%'

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have come across one online site that suggests the following is valid SQL statement....

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTS
WHERE Desc1 LIKE '[AMD]%'
```

It suggest that this will return all desc1 that commence with A, M, or D

I cannot get this to return results and have to do this

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTS
WHERE Desc1 LIKE 'A%' OR Desc1 LIKE 'M%' OR Desc1 LIKE 'D%'
```

I'm using Oracle Express 11g (XE) is the format '[AMD]%' correct ?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are referring to is SQL Server syntax.  Oracle has better support for regular expressions, so you would do:

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTS
WHERE regexp_like(Desc1, '^[AMD].*$');
```

Actually, the `.*$` is unnecessary, so you can write `WHERE regexp_like(Desc1, '^[AMD]'`.  A difference between `LIKE` patterns and regular expressions is that `LIKE` patterns match the whole string, but regular expressions only part of it.  When I use regular expressions in SQL, I often have them match the whole string, to avoid cognitive dissonance.

By the way, you can also do:

```
WHERE substr(DESC1, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'M', 'D')
```

Comment: Great help @Gordon Linoff, is there also Oracle Syntax to match or improve on the SQL Server syntax  SELECT * FROM PARTS WHERE GRP1 LIKE '[A-D]%'
indicating and GRP1 starting with any of the letters A,B,C or D ?

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle at least the query you found online looks wrong.
A correct version would be:

```
SELECT * FROM PARTS WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Desc1, '^[AMD]');
```

Have a look at Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm